# Parallax background image that fills container

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, parallax

I'm using stellar.js to apply a parallax effect to a background image. The height of the container around the background image is set by javascript to the window height minus the height of the header. I have the background image set to cover in css and want it to fill the container regardless of the screen size. This works fine with no parallax effect, but once I apply the parallax effect the positioning changes, so when the container is tall the image doesn't fill it.

I spoke to Mark Dalgleish, the creator of stellar.js to see if he had any ideas, and he said that the background image has to be taller than the container for it to fill it, which is pretty much the conclusion I had come to. So I'm wondering if there is a different way I can accomplish this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's the site I'm trying to make it work on. If you resize the browser window by pulling it in from the side and reload the page you will see what I mean. There's a gap below the image.
http://sonomarinwebdesign.com/agnitio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by using skrollr.js instead of stellar.js, and then setting the background image to "background-attachment: fixed" in the css. The scripts give a similar effect, but scrollr.js starts with the top offset at 0 so it doesn't leave a gap below the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this would work but something to try is to add javascript that runs when the page resizes:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
       // replace "100" with whatever makes it the best height:
       var newHeight = ($(window).height() - 100);
       var pictureHeight = 823;
       if (newHeight > pictureHeight) newHeight = pictureHeight;
       $(".an-yee-tsee-o.parallax.panel-pane").height(newHeight + "px");
    });
});
```

The point here is that you want to resize the parallax background panel when the window is resized. Even if this isn't quite right, hopefully it gets you on the right track. Best of luck!

*Note* - I was trying to fix the way the site looks when you load it on a "short" screen and then resize the browser larger. For your issue of the background not filling you can scale your background image up for that in a tool such as gimp for larger screens (or get a larger image to start with).

**EDIT** - Added code to make sure the div never ends up larger than the picture. You can also run this same code on load. It might not look as originally intended but it should work at least.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! This doesn't really solve my initial problem, however it makes the effect much nicer, so thank you for that! I went ahead and applied your code, so now maybe the problem will be more visible. If the browser size is tall you can see the gap below the image where it doesn't fill the container because of the parallax effect. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @JessicaBobier Added a simple check to make sure the height doesn't end up larger than the picture height. Thats about the best I can help with. The rest is up to you to get a larger picture! Best of luck!

Comment: I think this was kinda on the right track, but wouldn't really work because the image height is already scaling up and down with the window size. The problem was that the image was set to cover in css so it was the exact same height as the container div, but the stellar.js parallax script was offsetting the top positioning so that is has the parallax scroll effect. But I did finally solve the problem. I went with skrollr.js instead of stellar.js and now it works perfectly.